# Does the Incantatrix "Focused Study" affect classes other than the one progressed with it?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spellcasting

Title says it all basically. I need to know whether prohibited school that I choose when entering Incantatrix PrC is also prohibited for, let's say, Cleric that I progress as part of a multiclass character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer:

**Focused Studies** applies only to the spellcasting of any classes advanced with incantatrix.

### First, does a prohibited school apply to one class or all of them?

The incantatrix uses the same exact school prohibition rules that the wizard uses. **Focused Studies** says it works the same as the wizard's prohibited schools, and can't be a school already prohibited with the wizard version.

Let's look briefly at the wizard ability, found in the "School Specialization" sidebar on page 57 of the *Player's Handbook*:

> Spells of the prohibited school or schools are not available to the wizard, and she can’t even cast such spells from scrolls or fire them from wands.

This seems unambiguous. If the wizard specializes, they can't access spells from prohibited schools, no matter what. *Complete Arcane* (185) might claim that a specialist wizard can multiclass to gain access to prohibited schools, but in 3.5 D&D the primary source of a rule takes precedence, and *Complete Arcane* isn't the primary source for wizard rules; the *Player's Handbook* is. By saying it's not a primary source, could we disregard *Complete Arcane* the same way some people disregard *Complete Psionic*? Not really, no.

The primary source rule only applies when there's a conflict, and *Complete Arcane* isn't actually contradicting the *Player's Handbook*. Let's take a moment to look at the wizard's **Spells** feature, on page 56:

> ...To learn, prepare, or cast a spell, the wizard must have an Intelligence score equal to at least 10 + the spell level...

Read literally, this means that anyone with a level of wizard needs a high Intelligence score to cast a spell. If a 19th-level cleric took a single level of wizard, he'd need a 19 Int to cast his 9th-level cleric spells, because he has this wizard ability called **Spells** now that says so. This, of course, is blatantly incorrect; he needs a high Int only for his wizard spells, and a high Wis for his cleric spells. The *Player's Handbook* just doesn't make that explicit, because specifying "wizard spell" every time in the description of how wizards cast spells is unnecessary. It's implicit, even though we might wish for our game rules to be explicitly written.

The same thing is true, then, of prohibited schools: they apply only to spells cast from the class that imposes the prohibition, and if that's true of the wizard, it's true of the incantatrix, because incantatrix directly invokes the wizard ability.

### Second, what happens when incantatrix advances multiple classes?

A cleric 10/sorcerer 6/incantatrix 4 has a school prohibited for her sorcerer spells, but not her cleric spells, as we established. But incantatrix can advance the spellcasting of any class that granted 3rd-level arcane spells, so what happens with a sorcerer 6/wizard 5/incantatrix 9? Maybe (for some reason), they want to advance their spellcasting evenly, and alternate between advancing sorcerer and wizard with each incantatrix level.

Does **Focused Studies** apply to both their sorcerer and wizard spells, then, or only to whichever class they advanced when they gained their first level of incantatrix (which was the level at which they chose a prohibited school)? The rules are unclear, largely because the original rule, back in the PHB, was implicit.

At this point, it's a DM call, but purely mechanically I'd say that the prohibited school should apply to every spellcasting class advanced with incantatrix, because **Focused Studies** is supposed to apply for one's whole incantatrix career.

Comment: Reacted too quickly, but I think your wording can be tightened up here. “We can disregard _Complete Arcane_ the same way people disregard _Complete Psionics_,” should probably use “could” to introduce this as a hypothetical. Also, the comparison’s not great, since, as the following sections indicate, it’s **not** the same situation. (Also also, the title of the book is _Complete Psionic_, because its authors had **that little** regard for psionics.)

Comment: You're absolutely right; I've changed it. Originally I had more discussion around it with the gist that *Complete Arcane* doesn't have the authority to make any functional changes but fortunately that doesn't matter in this case, and some discussion of primary source vs. explicit nerfs, before deciding I'd strayed a little far from the actual point. What remained was, I agree, poorly worded, so I made it clearer that there's an illustrative comparison between *Complete Arcane* and *Complete Psionic* (that name *is* egregious), but an important distinction between the two cases.